# Drupal 7 field placeholder module add widget type

Tags: drupal, module, hook, extend

I am trying to learn how to use Drupal, and until i've been doing fine on my own. however there is one module that's teasing me - the Field Placeholder module.

basically what it does, it adds a placeholder entry to a field widget. per standard these widgets are text, number and mail modules. My problem is i can't figure out how i should extend the number of activated widgets, more specifically i want to add a placeholder attribute to the link module (https://drupal.org/project/link)

It says i can add other widgets via the hook_field_placeholder_info(), but how does that work?  The documentation for this module is very limited, so please help a noob :)

Answer (score 1):

Modules that provide an API, in this case defines `hook_field_placeholder_info`, usually have these functions defined in their `.api.php` file. For the `field_placeholder` module, that would be the `field_placeholder.api.php` file.

In there, you'll find:

```
/**
 * Define field placeholder supported widgets.
 *
 * @return
 *   An array whose keys are the widget names and whose value are the widget
 *   item where the placeholder will be attached.
 */
function hook_field_placeholder_info() {
  return array(
    'text_textfield' => 'value',
    'number' => 'value',
    'email_textfield' => 'email',
  );
}
```

From this, it looks like you need to implement this hook in your fork of the `link` module that returns an array something along the lines of:

```
function link_placeholder_info() {
  return array(
    'link_field' => 'value',
  );
}
```

Granted, I haven't looked in the `link` module to see what the actual values are, but that should get you going. It might be a good idea to take a look at the `text`, `number`, and `email` modules to see how those values in the example line up with the actual values in their respective modules too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, im still a little confused though, you say i should look for the value, but i don't really understand what that value is... What i've looked for would be an array key in the module's hook_field_info() implementations called what the value in the link api file specifies, eg. email, for email_textfield... but there isn't any array key, or anything else that makes the pattern  seem logical for me still :(

Comment: After looking at the `link` module, you're right, it just appends to the `element` array in its `hook_field_widget_form`. Maybe you could change it to how to the `number` module works? See the return line of the `number_field_widget_form` function here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!number!number.module/function/number_field_widget_form/7 Other than that, I'd say to read the code of the `field_placeholder` module to see how those values passed in `hook_placeholder_info` are used and see if it has to be a string or not.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I figured it out - as it turned out the `link` module differentiated from the number modules implementation of `hook_field_widget_form()` by only returning the element variable directly where the number widget returned it as an array... by making it return it like `array('value' => $element);` similar to the number, i managed to add it to the `placeholder` modules `field_placeholder_field_placeholder_info()` function similar to the other widgets - YAY :D

Comment: Well.... I should stop cheering too soon, cause as it turns out the placeholder entry only appeared in the admin interface, where i could define it as im used too for the other fields... but when i go to the form that displays the field, it's still blank :/ One thing i noticed in the link module is that the `hook_field_widget_form` implementation is very small compared to the number module's implementation.... @shanet i would love to hear what you think of this - thanks again.